# How do I get the data from Oracle database using PowerApps and show it in tabular format?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerapp

we have a requirement to pull data from the oracle database by using powerapps and show it in a tabular format.

any body who have worked on this type of requirement let us know how do we proceed on this?

Answer (score 1):

This guide will help you get started with Oracle connection.
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-powerapps-flow-and-logic-apps/

Comment: Please summarize the steps from the attached link then add the link as a reference! Thanks!